# Launching GUI application through Windows service is giving access denied on windows server

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, windows-server-2019

It's working fine when I try it on my local machine. The service is launching the application, but when the same Windows service is installed on the server, it does not work. It is installed and running, but the application is not launching. I have verified in the logs that it is throwing Access Denied.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether there is actually an **execution** permission set in this folder for this service (for the **NETWORK Service** Account), this is usually the error with Access Denied for Windows Services.